# Queuing asynchronous promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise

I'm using promises to query a rest api (using [httpplease](https://www.npmjs.com/package/httpplease) with the [Promise plug-in](https://github.com/matthewwithanm/httpplease-promises)):

```
api.call = function (myurl) {
    return http.get({
       "url" : myurl
    });
}
```

This returns a promise that I can use with something like:

```
api.call (myurl)
 .then (function (resp) {
    // do whatever with the data
 });
```

Now I'm trying to authenticate the api connection and for this I need to queue 2 async calls to the rest api:
1.- Ask for an authentication token
2.- Use the authentication token to make the actual call:

```
var getToken = function () {
    var tokenUrl = "....";
    return http.get({
       "url": tokenUrl;
    })
}
api.call = function (myurl) {
    return getToken().then(function (token) {
       return http.get({
          "url" : myurl,
          "headers" : {
             "auth-token": token
          }
       })
    })
}
```

The client code would remain the same:

```
api.call (myurl)
 .then (function (resp) {
    // do whatever with the data
 });
```

Unfortunately, the code above is returning the final promise before the first one finishes (ie, token is undef in the final "then").

I'm probably missing something, but I thought that this should work after reading [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-chaining):

> "If you return a value, the next "then" is called with that value.
>   However, if you return something promise-like, the next "then" waits
>   on it, and is only called when that promise settles (succeeds/fails)"

Any idea how to do this?

M;

EDIT: Fixed typo in code

Comment: What is `tokenUrl()`? Did you mean `getToken()`?

Comment: Yes, chaining promises in `.then()` calls like that should work. Make sure you `return` from everywhere.

Comment: Yes @Bergi, `tokenUrl()` should be `getToken()`. Fixed now in the OP.

Comment: `return getToken().then(function (token)` should process response object returned by `http.get`, i.e. `return getToken().then(function (response){ ... var token = response.data... }`

Comment: Usually when this happens to me it's because I'm *calling* a function when I meant to *pass* it somewhere, e.g. p.then(foo()). Your code looks good though, so check the code immediately calling it.

Comment: Please post your complete code that is needed to reproduce the issue. Currently, what you have posted will work.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, I have now found the problem and it lied outside of the "Promises" logic (a nasty bug!). At least your comments have helped me to stop looking at the wrong place!